# Using Decimal in Pi calculating program

Tags: c#

```
private static void GeneralPiCalc ()
{
    const int count = 100;
    const int zero = 0;
    decimal pi = 0m;
    for (int i = zero; i <= count; i = i + 2)
    {
        decimal d = (decimal)i;
        if (i % 4 == 0)
        {
            pi = pi + 4 / ((d + 2) * (d + 3) * (d + 4));
        }
        else
        {
            pi = pi - 4 / ((d + 2) * (d + 3) * (d + 4));
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine ("Pi is {0:D}", (3 + pi));
    Console.ReadLine ();
}
```

This is the code for my program. It keeps giving an:

> System.FormatException: Format specifier was invalid.
>
> at System.Number.FormatDecimal(Decimal value, String format, NumberFormatInfo info)
>   at System.Decimal.ToString(String format, IFormatProvider provider)
>   at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
>   at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
>   at System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine(String format, Object arg0)
>   at System.IO.TextWriter.SyncTextWriter.WriteLine(String format, Object arg0)
>   at System.Console.WriteLine(String format, Object arg0)
>   at PiCalc.MainClass.GeneralPiCalc() in >c:\Users\owner\Documents\Projects\PiCalc\PiCalc\Program.cs:line 33
>   at PiCalc.MainClass.Main(String[] args) in  c:\Users\owner\Documents\Projects\PiCalc\PiCalc\Program.cs:line 10

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation on `Decimal.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), decimals do not have a `D` format specifier.

> The format parameter can be any valid standard numeric format specifier except for **D**, R, and X, as well as any combination of custom numeric format specifiers.

You can view the [documentation on standard numeric format specifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to see what `decimal` does support for formatting

Comment: It's actually curious why there is a such limitation

Comment: What is life without whimsy?